# Recommended visualization libraries question - on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have an antique question (asked in 2011): [Recommended visualization libraries for standalone applications](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224/1352). Yes, we do have our [data-visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) tag, and this one asks about visualizing data (not, say, generating cartoons)... but it is so specifically about *software* that I would absolutely like to close it as off-topic, or migrate it to [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Any thoughts on this? Would moderators be able to migrate this?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is really off-topic. From https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "*if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here*". Does this question need statistical expertise? I'm inclined to think so. A possible risk is to get recommendations of software violating good practices relative to data visualization. I may be wrong (in particular when I don't know SR.SE very well), but to me this risk seems to be lower on CV.SE.

Comment: On the other hand, reading the answers, perhaps the question could be closed on other grounds ("needs more focus", etc.).

Comment: Exactly @J-J-J. The question, at the outset, has a dearth of focus, which is reflected in those big-list answers. And finally while it could be answered with a statistical perspective in mind, the question, in itself, doesn't explicitly specify anything.

Comment: As for whether to close/migrate legacy threads, check the related discussion: [When dealing with old off-topic questions, should we close or lock them, and why?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4827/when-dealing-with-old-off-topic-questions-should-we-close-or-lock-them-and-why)

Comment: I'm launching a vote to close this specific question, as even of SR.SE it would still have this lack of focus, which is probably against their rules https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @J-J-J, I vtc the post too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing to be aware of, in the context of these discussions, is that we cannot migrate old questions.

This question does not seem to be about statistics or data visualization in a meaningful sense.  The answers are mostly, 'try `package`'.  The whole thread is pretty uninformative.  I would argue that it should be closed.  I don't know that I believe it should be deleted, though.

Comment: I agree with this stance, gung (+1). I would say as per the norms, let the  mods lock it for good.

Comment: Thank you all, the question is now closed.